# Continue animation from where it was interupted - Core animation

Tags: ios, ios5, animation, core-animation, layer

I need a a little help with my animation.
I got two buttons, the first button calls an animation and the second one calls another animation.

Now when I press the first button a code like this one down below will be called. 
The Problem is that when I press the second button the animation kinda teleports to it's starting position (second animations position), is there a way to make the animations flow together from where it was interupted?

```
CABasicAnimation *anim1 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
anim1.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
anim1.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((-10*M_PI)/180)];
anim1.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((10*M_PI)/180)];
anim1.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim1.autoreverses = YES;
anim1.duration = .5;
[head addAnimation:anim1 forKey:@"transform"];
```

Virtual picture:

http://i47.tinypic.com/2yopif6.jpg

The black line is the first animation, the red is the second animation, and the green is the one I'm trying to figure out. According to the picture it was interupted in the middle of the black.

Comment: Please post the code for the second animation

Comment: It's almost the same code just with a higher fromValue and toValue, to make the rotation bigger.

Comment: If you explicitly state a _from_ value for your animation then that is your problem.

Comment: When I try to pass nil to the FromValue on the second animation it just starts from it's original position when the block was drawn.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using the animation method instead of the UIView class - just make sure you use the **UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState** option?

Check the reference doc here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

**EDIT**

I think this tutorial will help you better: http://wangling.me/2011/06/core-animation-101-from-and-to/. What they are trying to achieve there is to bounce a ball after triggering the animation through a button. When the button is pressed a second time the ball should bounce back from the current position. There is a section where they mention they rely on 2 delegates method animationDidStart and animationDidStop to implement this desired effect.

Comment: As already mentioned by David - please post the second animation.

Comment: I'm looking for the equivilient to UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState but for CABasicAnimation. l'll try to be a bit clearer: Imagine I want an old clock ticker thing, the first animation goes from say. -45 to 45 degrees and then it goes back and forth until the next animation goes from say -60 to 60. I want to be able to switch between these but without the "teleport" to startposition during the animation. The code on both methods is like the one up there but with different angles.